# How to acces column elements-data using jQuery DataTables and checkboxes as row selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatables

I want to access the row data in my jQuery datatable when I select a row using a checkbox. I already know how to access the row data but it's returned as a string and I need to use javascript string functions to split the data and get the values that I want; I don't know if that would work when there's a over 10k rows of data in my table.

Is there a way to access specific values of a row using a checkbox as a row selector, right now all I want is to get the rowId of the row selected, this Id is stored in the checkbox column of the table.

Here it's the HTML of my table

```
<table id="MyTable" class="display table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Last Name
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                Age
                <br>
            </th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody id="tablePersons">
        <tr id="PersonId" style="display:none" class="result-item">

            <td></td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my datatable definiton

```
var personTable= $('#MyTable').DataTable({
            bInfo: false, paging: false, bInfo : false,
            dom: 'lrtp',
            columnDefs: [ {
                    targets:   0,
                    checkboxes: {
                        selectRow: true
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    targets: 1,
                    className: 'textcolumn-left'
                }, 
                {
                    targets: 2,
                    className: 'textcolumn-left'
                },
                {
                    targets: 3,
                    className: 'textcolumn-left'
                }
            ]
            });
```

here is how I add a row

```
personTable.row.add(['<input class="personTableCheckboxes" type="checkbox"  value="'+item.personID+'"  id="'+item.personID+'"> ',
                item.name, item.lastName, item.age]);
```

and here is how I get the row data

```
var listOfCheckedRows = personTable.column(0).checkboxes.selected();
```

if I do a `console.log(listOfCheckedRows)` I get an array that I can iterate, if I iterate it  like this

```
$.each(listOfCheckedRows , function(index, rowId){
            console.log(rowId) ;

        });
```

that console.log inside the $.each loop contains a string that contains the html of the row with the data, I can do javascript string function to split the string and get the id of the checkbox that represents the id of the row, but I don't want to do this since this could not be eficient if the table has over 10k rows.

I want to iterate that array and get all the row ids and store it in another array, is there a way taht I can get the id value of the checkboxes that are selected? without doing this for each loop or the string split function to get the id of the checkbox element that represents the row id.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly this should work:

**EDIT2**

```
var arrId = [];
$.each(listOfCheckedRows , function(index, row){
    arrId.push($(row).attr('id'));
});
```

```js
var row = '<input class="personTableCheckboxes" type="checkbox" value="6" id="6">';

console.log($(row).attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if I do a console.log of row I get this: `["<input class="personTableCheckboxes" type="checkbox"  value="6"  id="6"> ", "Jhon", "Smith", "44"]`, but I try your answer and I get and array of undefined, I tried using row().data() and I get this `["", "", "", "", DT_RowId: "id="PersonId""]`

Comment: @TorkB80 Try now

Comment: I get a syntax error: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at String.<anonymous> (undefined:1410)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (undefined:1406)`

Comment: That's weird. I added a snippet to check if it works and it does. Well, I'm afraid I can't help you more. I wish you good luck.

Comment: sorry the console.log of row displays this `<input class="personTableCheckboxes" type="checkbox" value="6" id="6">` it is not an array it's a string

Comment: @TorkB80 Ok, try now.

Answer (score 0):

```
//check the checkboxes and get data from foreach
<th>
<input type="checkbox" value="Check all" class="check-all" style="display: inline;"> Select all
</th>

<?php foreach ($orders as $value) { ?>
  <td>
    <input class='check-this pid' value="<?= $value->pid; ?>" type="checkbox" style="display: inline;">
  </td>
<?php } ?>

//check all using jQuery.

$('.check-all:checkbox').change(function(){
        if($(".check-all").prop('checked') == true){

        $('.check-this').prop('checked','checked');

        }
    else {
        $('.check-this').removeAttr('checked');
    }  
})

//get data 
  var pArr = [];

  $('#example').find(".pid").each(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
          pArr.push($(this).val());
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding row like shown below and then redrawing the table with `draw()`.

```
personTable.row.add([item.personID, item.name, item.lastName, item.age]);
```

Then `checkboxes.selected()` will return a list containing person IDs.

If you need extra information about selected rows, you could use the code below:

```
var data = personTable.rows({ selected: true }).data();
```